# Push notification is not working in iPhone 6 with iOS 8.0

Tags: ios, ios8, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

I am working on iPhone application using Push Notification. I am having a notification issue, I am getting device token id successfully in iOS 6, 7, 8.1, 8.1.2, but for my iPhone 6 with iOS 8.0.

So in my push notification method "didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken", token id is returning nil. So, I can't able to get push notification. I don't know what is the problem.

Here is my code :

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{        
    if ([application respondsToSelector:@selector(registerUserNotificationSettings:)]) {
        [application registerUserNotificationSettings:[UIUserNotificationSettings settingsForTypes:UIUserNotificationTypeAlert|UIUserNotificationTypeBadge|UIUserNotificationTypeSound categories:nil]];
    }
    else{
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotificationTypes:
         (UIRemoteNotificationTypeBadge | UIRemoteNotificationTypeSound | UIRemoteNotificationTypeAlert)];
    }
    .
    .
    .
    .

    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

    return YES;
}

- (void)application:(UIApplication*)application didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:(NSData*)deviceToken
{
    NSString *newToken = [deviceToken description];
    newToken = [newToken stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@"<>"]];
    newToken = [newToken stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@""];

    [GlobalVariables proTrain].deviceToken = newToken;

    NSLog(@"device token id = %@", newToken);
}

- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didRegisterUserNotificationSettings:(UIUserNotificationSettings *)notificationSettings {
    [application registerForRemoteNotifications];
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
#define IS_OS_8_OR_LATER    ([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] floatValue] >= 8.0)

if (IS_OS_8_OR_LATER)
{
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerUserNotificationSettings:[UIUserNotificationSettings settingsForTypes:(UIUserNotificationTypeSound | UIUserNotificationTypeAlert | UIUserNotificationTypeBadge) categories:nil]];
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotifications];
}
else
{
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotificationTypes:UIRemoteNotificationTypeAlert | UIRemoteNotificationTypeBadge | UIRemoteNotificationTypeSound];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe instead of this:

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotificationTypes:
     (UIRemoteNotificationTypeBadge | UIRemoteNotificationTypeSound | UIRemoteNotificationTypeAlert)];
```

Try this:

```
[application registerForRemoteNotificationTypes:
     (UIRemoteNotificationTypeBadge | UIRemoteNotificationTypeSound | UIRemoteNotificationTypeAlert)];
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but i am getting problem in iOS8.0, so after replacing above code should not work.

Answer (score 0):

```
/*--- Setup Push Notification ---*/
    //For iOS 8
if ([UIApplication instancesRespondToSelector:@selector(registerUserNotificationSettings:)] && [UIApplication instancesRespondToSelector:@selector(registerForRemoteNotifications)])
{
    UIUserNotificationSettings *settings = [UIUserNotificationSettings settingsForTypes:(UIUserNotificationTypeBadge | UIUserNotificationTypeSound | UIUserNotificationTypeAlert) categories:nil];
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerUserNotificationSettings:settings];

}
//For iOS 7 & less
else if ([UIApplication instancesRespondToSelector:@selector(registerForRemoteNotificationTypes:)])
{
    UIRemoteNotificationType myTypes = UIRemoteNotificationTypeBadge | UIRemoteNotificationTypeAlert | UIRemoteNotificationTypeSound;
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotificationTypes:myTypes];
}
```

The notifications methods are as follows :

```
#ifdef __IPHONE_8_0
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didRegisterUserNotificationSettings:(UIUserNotificationSettings *)notificationSettings
{
    //register to receive notifications
    [application registerForRemoteNotifications];
}

- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application handleActionWithIdentifier:(NSString *)identifier forRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo completionHandler:(void(^)())completionHandler
{
    //handle the actions
    if ([identifier isEqualToString:@"declineAction"]){
    }
    else if ([identifier isEqualToString:@"answerAction"]){
        NSLog(@"didReceiveRemoteNotification ios 8");// push some specific view when notification received       
    }
}
#endif

- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:(NSData *)deviceToken
{
    self.strDeviceToken = [[[deviceToken description] stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@"<>"]] stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@""];
    NSLog(@"Device Token ==== %@", self.strDeviceToken);
}

- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError:(NSError *)error {
    NSLog(@"error : %@",error.localizedDescription);
}

- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo
{
    NSLog(@"didReceiveRemoteNotification  ios 7");// push some specific view when notification received

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  if ([application respondsToSelector:@selector(isRegisteredForRemoteNotifications)])
    {
        // iOS 8 Notifications
        [application registerUserNotificationSettings:[UIUserNotificationSettings settingsForTypes:(UIUserNotificationTypeSound | UIUserNotificationTypeAlert | UIUserNotificationTypeBadge) categories:nil]];

        [application registerForRemoteNotifications];
    }
    else
    {
        // iOS < 8 Notifications
        [application registerForRemoteNotificationTypes:
         (UIUserNotificationTypeBadge | UIUserNotificationTypeSound | UIUserNotificationTypeAlert)];
    }
```